# Convert POSIX date and time to UNIX time in R

Tags: r, datetime, unix-timestamp, posixct

I am looking for a way to convert a simple POSIX time stamp like this

```
> time
[1] "2014-02-19 17:40:41"
```

into an UNIX time stamp. All solutions I found only worked the other way round. Can anybody provide some help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2014-02-20"))
```

From `?POSIXct`

```
There are two basic classes of date/times. Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed)
number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC timezone) as a numeric vector.
```